# How can I perform unit test in ember.js ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, ember.js

I've been developing a web application where I'm using ember.js 1.0. I was wondering if there is any way or framework to make unit test in ember.

For instance, suppose that I've a controller called "CustomerController" and I have a method to add need items to a shopping cart.

```js
...
addNewItem : function(item){
    var content = shoppingCart.get("content");
    content.push(item);
    shoppingCart.set("content", content);
}
...
```

So i want to perform a unit test to see if the number of items increase when the customer add a new item. What kind of framework I can used to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Qunit works well with ember and has great async support. It's used to test ember itself.

Check out [ember-app-kit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit), which uses qunit and the karma test runner. It includes a couple example tests, as well as some intro articles referenced in the "Getting Started" section of the README.

Answer (score 2):

Best way for this is using Jasmine

There is a blog post explaining your answer completely here:

[Unit Testing Ember.js, How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Runloop](http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2012/04/03/testing-ember-and-the-runloop/)